How can I list the hosts in my ssh config file sequentially by lan ip using general.community.ssh_config?
Here's the play I came up with, and I listed the inventory in the order that I want within the group. I would like my config file to be in the following order:
Host node1 10.0.0.30
  HostName 10.0.0.30
  ...

Host node2 10.0.0.31
  HostName 10.0.0.30
  ...

Host node3 10.0.0.32
  HostName 10.0.0.30
  ...


My current attempt at achieving this

I swear it worked once and then just stopped after I tweaked it a little more...

- name: Generate SSH config sequentially by LAN IP
  delegate_to: localhost
  community.general.ssh_config:
    ssh_config_file: "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/.ssh/config"
    state: present
    host: "{{ item.inventory_hostname }}"
    hostname: "{{ item.ansible_host }}"
    remote_user: "{{ item.ansible_user }}"
    port: "{{ item.hostport | default(22) }}"
    identity_file: "{{ item.ssh_privatekey }}"
  loop: "{{ play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) | sort(attribute='ansible_host') }}"


I swear it worked once... <= wild guess: it worked the very first time when it created the file. Now that the file exists, it adds the new hosts at the end of the file leaving the existing ones where they already are. This is totally expected. Workaround: delete the file before recreating it (but that will break idempotency)
